# Download de Arquivos PDF em ReactJs

Tags: javascript, pdf, download, react, axios

Estou com um pequeno problema em realizar download de arquivos em PDF

Tenho uma **API** que retorna um **array** de bytes com o *type*: `"application/pdf"`, se eu chamar direto no navegador minha rota.

Ex: `localhost/api/download/pdf/{id}`

O download do PDF é realizado sem problemas nenhum

Mas no **react**, eu estou usando o `axios` para realizar a requisição `get` a minha API e estou usando o [react-file-download](https://github.com/kennethjiang/react-file-download) para fazer o download do DATA da resposta, mas o PDF montado está vindo em branco

Faço download para outros formatos, como CSV e TXT, da mesma forma, usando o  `react-file-download` e eles são realizado sem o menor problema

mas com PDF eu estou tendo esse problema

eu salvei o data que esta chegando na resposta do axios
esse é o resultado: https://pastebin.com/FkL8snWr

nesse momento estou "contornando" o problema usando window.location.href para fazer a chamado ao endereço da minha API.
Ex: window.location.href = localhost/api/download/pdf/{id}

o download é realizando normalmente

alguem ja passou por isso?
como vcs fazer o download de PDF, ou outros arquivos?

Comment: O download de um arquivo funciona apenas no caso de solicitação 'GET'. Você pode simplesmente criar uma API que aceite uma solicitação 'GET'. E do lado do cliente, em alguma ação Você pode chamar window.open ('server full url with api path').

E iniciar o download do seu arquivo.

Answer (score -2):

Tente por no axios set o `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` que assim ele vai.

Comment: Utilize os comentários para enviar saudações...